# Upgraded spring boot from 2.1.9 to 2.2.0 , now getting exception while starting

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I upgraded spring boot from 2.1.9 to 2.2.0 now I am facing some exception while starting the application

java       :  openjdk11
   spring-boot:  v2.2.0.RELEASE

I tried by deleting the jar from this below location and did mvn clean install, still no luck.

.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar

error :

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.health.DiscoveryCompositeHealthIndicator.<init>(DiscoveryCompositeHealthIndicator.java:41)

The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator.<init>(Lorg/springframework/boot/actuate/health/HealthAggregator;)V

The method's class, org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/regosa/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/CompositeHealthIndicator.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/regosa/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.xxxxx.business.workflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxxxx-component-workflow-starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>xxxxx-component-workflow-starter</name>
    <description>xxxxx-component-workflow-starter</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <jaxb-runtime.version>2.4.0-b180830.0438</jaxb-runtime.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.M1</spring-cloud.version>
       <zeebe-version>0.20.1</zeebe-version>    
        <google-guava.version>27.0.1-jre</google-guava.version>
        <xxxxx.version>1.0</xxxxx.version>
        <swagger.version>2.9.2</swagger.version>
        <jjwt.version>0.9.1</jjwt.version>
        <json.version>20180813</json.version>
        <slf4j-api.version>1.7.25</slf4j-api.version>
        <mysql.version>8.0.11</mysql.version>
        <mongo-java-driver.version>3.10.1</mongo-java-driver.version>
        <commons-io.version>2.6</commons-io.version>
        <commons-lang.version>2.6</commons-lang.version>
        <commons-pool2.version>2.5.0</commons-pool2.version>
        <redis.version>3.1.0</redis.version>
        <velocity.version>1.7</velocity.version>
        <velocity-tools.version>2.0</velocity-tools.version>
        <logstash-logback-encoder.version>5.3</logstash-logback-encoder.version>
        <httpclient.version>4.5.6</httpclient.version>
        <jaxb-runtime.version>2.4.0-b180830.0438</jaxb-runtime.version>
        <env>local</env>
    </properties>   

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Start: Spring Libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End: Spring Libraries -->

        <!-- Adding JAXB Runtime since it is not shipped with JDK 9+ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb-runtime.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Start: xxxxx Libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxxx-entity</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxxx-redis</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxxx-mongo</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxx.version}</version>
        </dependency>           
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxxx-util</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxx.model</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxxx-model</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxx.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxxx-common-service</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxx.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxxx-common-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxx.version}</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxx.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxxx-common-security</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxx.version}</version>
        </dependency>           
        <!-- End: xxxxx Libraries -->

        <!--  Adding Zeebe client as part of the Spring Startup -->     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zeebe</groupId>
            <artifactId>zeebe-client-java</artifactId>
            <version>${zeebe-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${google-guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logstash Log Encoder -->
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId> 
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId> 
            <version>${logstash-logback-encoder.version}</version> 
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${mongo-java-driver.version}</version>
        </dependency>       

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-pool2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-pool2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/redis.clients/jedis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>${redis.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Start: Swagger Libraries -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End: Swagger Libraries -->

        <!-- Start: Spring Boot and Security Test Libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End: Spring Boot and Security Test Libraries -->

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <finalName>xxxxx-component-workflow-starter</finalName>
        <filters>
            <filter>${env}-build.properties</filter>
        </filters>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${java.version}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                <archive>
                  <manifestEntries>
                    <Automatic-Module-Name>com.xxxxx.business.workflow.component.starter</Automatic-Module-Name>
                  </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories> 
</project>
```

New exception :

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.data.rest.core.support.UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory.<init>(UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory.java:57)

The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry.of(Ljava/util/List;)Lorg/springframework/plugin/core/PluginRegistry;

The method's class, org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/regosa/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/plugin/core/PluginRegistry.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/regosa/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry
```

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsManager.createContextBuilder(DocumentationPluginsManager.java:152)

The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry.getPluginFor(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/springframework/plugin/core/Plugin;)Lorg/springframework/plugin/core/Plugin;

The method's class, org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/regosa/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/2.0.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/plugin/core/PluginRegistry.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/regosa/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/2.0.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please post your pom.xml

Comment: @EugenCovaci attached pom.xl

Comment: Please replace `Greenwich.M1` with `Greenwich.RELEASE`, see if the error is gone.

Comment: The latest version is `Greenwich.SR3`, you may try this as well..

Comment: @EugenCovaci Thanks. Now i getting another which says method missing in spring-plugin-core jar.. I updated the question above. which plugin i have to update now..?

Answer (score 16):

In short, issue is due to spring cloud and spring boot version incompatibility, spring boot 2.2.X requires Hoxton release train instead of Greenwich. See below for more info.

This issue is due to spring-cloud.version incompatibility. As per spring cloud documentation link(https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud), below is the spring boot compatibility:

**Release train Spring Boot compatibility**

```
Release Train      Boot Version

  Hoxton             2.2.x

  Greenwich          2.1.x
```

So if you are updating spring boot to 2.2.x then update to Hoxton release train for spring cloud as well i.e Hoxton.RC1(https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/25/spring-cloud-hoxton-rc1-released)

P.S: As per spring cloud Milestone page Hoxton.RELEASE in due on Nov 18, 2019 (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/milestones)

Comment: ref: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/3410

Comment: This worked for me. I was using Greenwich.RELEASE with Spring Boot 2.2.4 which started giving issues with when i started using the spring-boot-starter-actuator. Same error logs as mentioned in the question. Updated to Hoxton.SR1 and it started successfully.

Answer (score 8):

Actually springfox ist not compatible with Spring-Boot 2.2.0. It seems that springfox is dead at all.

Instead you can use: SpringDoc OpenApi

Comment: is there any other libraries available. instead of swagger?

Comment: @JoysonRego Spring REST Docs is awesome but follows another approach.

Comment: @JoysonRego yes, here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58953513/any-springfox-alternatives-out-there

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a known issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/3410

If you use Spring Cloud dependencies in your Spring Boot application make sure you have the correct Spring Cloud version on classpath! Only Spring Cloud's "Hoxton" ([https://spring.io/blog/2019/08/19/spring-cloud-hoxton-m2-released)](https://spring.io/blog/2019/08/19/spring-cloud-hoxton-m2-released) release train currently support Spring Boot 2.2.

Comment: thanks, now i am geting another exception. i updated above in question

Comment: it was a mistake.  Do i need to update any library?

Comment: Confirming `Greenwich.SR3` doesn't work with `Spring Boot 2.2.0` 
you need to add `maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }` and replace Greenwich on `Hoxton.RC1`

Answer (score 3):

**Update your springfox-swagger version. I have upgraded springfox 2.9.2 running with boot 2.2.2**

SpringFox needs version 1.2.0 version but Spring Boot 2.2.2 itself does not pull this in.So you somehow got spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE in your classpath.Then it will work fine

Answer (score 2):

As [user10871691](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58547255/265954) and [P3arl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59715937/265954) have already noted, the `spring-plugin-core` dependency is resolved with the wrong version `1.2.0.RELEASE`. In order to force usage of the correct `2.0.0.RELEASE`, you have to

- EITHER exclude the wrong transitive dependency and specify the correct one,
- OR pin (!) that dependency version in your `pom.xml`. This is done in the `<dependenciesManagement>` block, not in the `<dependencies>` block.

Example for Springfox 3.0.0 using version pinning in the `<dependenciesManagement>` block:

```
<spring-plugin-core.version>2.0.0.RELEASE</spring-plugin-core.version>
<springfox.version>3.0.0</springfox.version>
...

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- Fix wrong resolved `spring-plugin-core` dependency version for springfox -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-plugin-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- API Documentation -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>${springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
  <!-- API Documentation -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! I had spent days of confusion trying to figure out where my issue is originating from!

Answer (score 1):

```
<springBootVersion>2.2.4.RELEASE</springBootVersion>
```

Supported Cloud version.  Hoxton.M2

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Hoxton.M2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's strange. The `spring-plugin-core` version should be `2.0.0`, not `1.2.0`. Let's upgrade it:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.plugin/spring-plugin-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Still, no luck getting some other exception from the spring-plugin-core library  (no method found.). I have updated the error message in the above question

Comment: @JoysonRego Run `mvn dependency:tree` and paste the result bellow the errors.

Comment: here is the  dependency tree link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gayvvVe_VsB1P2Hi2rcwRw8NdK89qtbq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: latest pom file link  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qva534d2biDCx0T4ibkR4UdCNtDs-lMi/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @JoysonRego I don't think you can make it work, unless you give up the `springfox` dependencies. They are using an older version of  `spring-plugin-core`.

Comment: is there any library instead of swagger?

Comment: @JoysonRego Not really.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue and after adding the updated plugin-core dependency. It is resolved now.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE is not working in your project then another approach is that to use springfox-swagger with **3.0.0-SNAPSHOT** version. For this version it has different repository. 
Repository url : http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/

It will use @EnableSwagger2WebMvc annotation instead of @EnableSwagger2.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to Springfox Swagger2 to 3.0.0 version and spring plugin code to 2.0.0.RELEASE version. It worked for me.
Spring Boot Version - 2.3.9.RELEASE

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```